# Exercise in Tarski's Introduction to Logic

Tags: logic, model-theory

In Chapter 6 Exercise 9 (p.145) of [*Introduction to Logic*](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/048628462X), Tarski asks the reader to prove that the following statements, taken as axioms, are independent:

> ****Theorem III****. For any elements $x$, $y$, and $z$ of the set $S$, if $x\cong y$ and $x\cong z$, then $y\cong z$.
>
> ****Theorem IV****. For any elements $x$, $y$, and $z$ of the set $S$, if $x\cong y$ and $y\cong z$, then $z\cong x$.
>
> ****Theorem V.**** For any elements $x$, $y$, $z$, and $t$ of the set $S$, if $x\cong y$, $y\cong z$, and $z\cong t$, then $x\cong t$.

No other axioms appear to be assumed in the question, and Tarski seems to be using the $\cong $  symbol here to designate any relation whatsoever, not necessary an equivalence relation (for an example of this usage, see pp.121-124).

My problem: I have not yet found a model where (III) and (IV) hold while (V) fails. In fact, I seem to be able to prove that (III) and (IV) imply (V). Here is my argument (Edit: thanks to @DanielV for providing a much simpler argument, reproduced here):

> Suppose $x\cong y\cong z\cong t$. Then $z\cong x$ follows from (IV). By (III), $z\cong x$ and $z \cong t$ give us $x\cong t$, as needed. $\square$

My question: What am I missing? Assuming I am wrong, I would appreciate learning the error in my argument and, ideally, seeing an example of a model in which (III) and (IV) hold but (V) fails.

Comment: If $a \to b \to c \to d$ then by IV $c \to a$ then by III $d \to a$ which establishes V.

Comment: @DanielV I think you mean $a \to d$. But yes, that is a much simpler argument. I will edit my post to reflect yours. 

So, doesn't this mean Tarski was wrong?

Comment: your argument looks right to me. perhaps Tarski meant that the axioms are *pairwise* independent?

Comment: @AtticusStonestrom his exact instructions are "exhibit models satisfying (a) the first two sentences of the system, but not the last; (b) the first and third sentence, but not the second; (c) the last two sentences, but not the first." So I think he doesn't mean pairwise independence.

Comment: ah, I have looked inside the link you gave; here is perhaps the source of the confusion. Tarski says to "consider the system of sentences (a) of exercise 7", which appears to consist of Axiom I, Theorem I, and Theorem II

Comment: I think you are perhaps meant to construct models of the kind you describe for *those* three sentences, rather than for Theorem III, Theorem IV, and Theorem V. however I do not have access to Axiom I or Theorem I or Theorem II in the book preview, so I cannot say whether the exercise is possible with those sentences. does this suggestion look right to you?

Comment: @AtticusStonestrom You are right. Thank you for helping me resolve my confusion!

Comment: @DanielWest my pleasure, happy it helped!! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*IMO, the problem is stated diffrently*

Show that the three following "axioms" are independent: [Axiom I and Theorems I and II of Sect.37](https://books.google.it/books?id=5MeNCgAAQBAJ&pg=PA145), that are:

> $\text {Ax.I } x \cong x \text { (Reflex)}$

> $\text {Th.I } \text { if } y \cong z, \text { then } z \cong y \text { (Symm)}$

> $\text {Th.II } \text { if } x \cong y \text { and } y \cong z, \text { then } x \cong z \text { (Trans)}$